# C# Listener (server) for TCP/IP Using Serial Connection (COM) / DotRas / PPP

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, serial-port, dotras

I am working on an application which will run on a Windows 10 Laptop to receive data from a connected device.

As a requirement from the business, the application must use the TCP/IP via serial port (or USB/Serial) and NOT be connected using ethernet.

I have been able to configure a test **client** using the [DotRas](https://dotras.codeplex.com/) wrapper for the winodws RasDial api, but have yet to find any documentation or other implementation for the **server** side of the connection.

Since the **server** is actually what I need; I am reaching out to see if anyone has implemented software to listen on TCP/IP via Serial or if anyone has any ideas on where I can further research this option.

I do not have any code to post, as all the code i have written thus far uses the [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) classes which do not quite meet the needs.

I am open to any suggestions, including using native c or c++ to achieve the goal - though I could not find anything for those languages either that were short of re-writing PPP.

Comment: The documtation on DotRas is appalling to say the least. It would appear that clients are PPTP clients, so I would suggest researching that. [I found this from a cursory search](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/vpn.server.pptpd), I suspect you should be able to find something if you look for PPTP sever. Sorry not to have more.

Comment: Thank Kevin - I'll check it out - i'm open to any ideas.